# How to display unknown text in telugu format in android

Tags: android, fonts

I am developing an app which display text in telugu.i get the text through rss feeds, when we open using xml viewer it shows in telugu but when we get these text using parser it displays like this
" **à°¦à°³à°¾à°°à±à°²à°¨à± à°ªà±à°·à°¿à°¸à±à°¤à±à°¨à±à°¨ à°¬à°¾à°¬à±** ". Please help me how to display text in telugu and i also set the typeface and also use get text from html.

Answer (score 0):

To show Telugu or any other language in your mobile/emulator, the mobile has to support that language. Then only that font will visible properly. To check your mobile supports the telugu language **Settings->Language and input-->Language**

Comment: Thanks for your response but my problem is I am using different rss feeds to display content.all of them are display content in telugu but when we get data using xml parser techniques some of them shows content in telugu and some of them are showing format like this à°¦à°³à°¾à°°à±à°²à°¨à± à°ªà±à°·à°¿à°¸à±à°¤à±à°¨à±à°¨ à°¬à°¾à°¬à±  .
please help me.